# Composite PK in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

I have the following:

```
create table dbo.Packs
(
  Id int identity not null
    constraint Packs_Id_PK primary key clustered (Id)
);

create table dbo.Files
(
  Id int not null  
  Data varbinary (max) filestream null
    constraint Files_Data_DF default (0x),  
  [Key] uniqueidentifier rowguidcol not null
    constraint Files_Key_U unique,      
  Mime nvarchar (200) not null,
    constraint Id_Mime_PK primary key clustered (Id, Mime)
) filestream_on [STORAGE];

alter table dbo.Files
add constraint Files_Id_FK foreign key (Id) references dbo.Packs(Id) on delete cascade on update cascade;
```

I am looking for table splitting. So:

- The File Id would be the same as the Pack Id.
- A Pack can have one or many files. Each file has a different mime.
- The PK in files would be created from its ID and MIME. So this is unique.

Basically, pack could have the following rows:

PACKS
Id
1
2

And files would be the following:

FILES
Id   Mime
1    image/jpg    PK = (1, image/jpg)    (PACK ID = 1)
1    image/gif    PK = (1, image/gif)    (PACK ID = 1)
2    image/jpg    PK = (2, image/jpg)    (PACK ID = 2)

The File ID is the same as the Pack ID to which it is associated.

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: Did you try it? It's dead simple to *run* your code, write a handful of INSERT statements, and see whether things work like you expected.

Answer (score 0):

If each file has a different value for "Mime", then "Mime" should be declared UNIQUE.  If "Mime" is unique, then the set {Id, Mime} is also unique.

Comment: Yes, for each file the mime is unique. And the id is the same as the id to which the file is associated. So {Id, Mime} is and should always be unique. I just updated my code with a table example. Could you post a example on how I should do it then ...

Comment: That means a particular pack isn't allowed to contain two "image/jpg" files. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Yes! That is it ... A Pack is a wrapper to hold different versions of a file ... Not different files. So for each pack I want all files to share its ID and the mimes should all be different.